# Removing control from angular 2 dynamic form breaks submit binding

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I've tried to remove control from dynamic form, but after doing this, the form submit event is no longer handled by angular.

```
this.dynamicForm.removeControl(key);
```

After calling this method, if click on submit button, the form is submitted as usual instead of sending the XmlHttpRequest.

Does anybody has any clue what else should be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you prevent click event during `onSubmit($event)` method handling? 
    `event.preventDefault();` 
or 
    `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Comment: No. If I remove this function call and leave form untouched in the state it was created, the submit works. Only when I make this change, the binging is "broken".